# TextToSpeech : deprecated speak function in API Level 21

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I try to use a TextToSpeech in my app,

```
String text = editText.getText().toString();
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

But the function speak(String text, int queueMode, HashMap params)  is deprecated in API Level 21. Instead of that, it is adviced to use speak(CharSequence text, int queueMode, Bundle params, String utteranceId). 
But I don't know how to set it. Thanks

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
String text = editText.getText().toString();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    tts.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
} else {
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Comment: When I use your suggestion, Android Studio says: "params="null" utteranceId="null" and unwrap if statement suggestions. And, it didn't help enough to my case.

Comment: Build.VERSION_CODES is now obsolete (April 2021). Simply replace above conditional (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop) ... etc

Answer (score -1):

Here is the complete work that work for me

```
Private TextToSpeech ts
 ts=new TextToSpeech(CurrentActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                String text = "Any Text to Speak";
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    ts.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
                } else {
                    ts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }

            }
        });
```